# How to load plugins on the fly?

Tags: vim

A partner and I are maintaining [Vimified](http://zaiste.github.io/vimified/), a Vim configuration project, using [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle).

With the time going, the configuration file is growing as we try to propose best configurations for more and more languages.

We have package management ([read more](https://github.com/zaiste/vimified#packages)) which allows you to install only the bundle that have a role for what you care about.

Like in my company, there is a lot of polyglot programmers. And we started wondering what could be a better way to make Vim faster even if I need to support lots of languages as I know many languages.

And so, we started saying: *What if we can load plugins on the fly according to the file extension?*

We know that by default Vim changes its configuration based on the file extension (eg. the syntax). We started figuring out that we could also use `autocmd` but after an hour or two, I didn't manage to find how to do it.

Would anyone have an idea? Or is it even really possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Language-specific plugins should reside in the `ftplugin/` subdirectory and define their functionality for the current buffer only. This way, they only get loaded when that *filetype* is edited, and your Vim startup stays lean and fast.

General-purpose plugins (i.e. stuff that applies to all kinds of buffers) are installed by the user; with a plugin manager like *Vundle*, this boils down to a single line in your `~/.vimrc` and a single command; I don't think it can get easier than that.

With the *autoload* mechanism introduced in Vim 7, plugins need only define their autocmds, mappings, and commands in `plugin/<name>.vim`, the long actual implementation is then sourced on-demand when first used. This is your best ally in keeping Vim startup costs down.

Instead of inventing another complex package management scheme (which invariably confuses users with its new conventions; see the many questions around distributions like *spf-13* and *Janus*), consistent use of existing schemes should be able to make Vim startup and bloat a non-issue, and it will benefit all plugin users, not just those moving to your scheme.

Vim "distributions" lure you with a quick install and out of the box settings, but you pay the price with increased complexity (you need to understand both Vim's runtime loading scheme and the arbitrary conventions of the distribution) and inflexibility (the distribution may make some things easier, but other things very difficult). Vim is incredibly customizable, using someone else's customization makes no sense.

Comment: I got distracted from writing my answer and what do I see when I come back to my textfield? The exact same answer, written by Ingo Karkat.

Comment: @romainl: That effect may be due to the fact that I've adopted some of your arguments against Vim distributions... somehow, I knew you would be attracted to this question; I'm glad you agree with my answer :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Vimified is merely something for Vim beginners and is thought for generic purposes with really easy way to expand/change it. Other than this point, I'm not english-ish by birth so I'm not sure I understand well all the elements you pointed out. Am I wrong or it is not possible then to load third plugins according to the file extension of the current buffer except hoping each plugins loads only when needed? Because looking at Vundle sources, it seems it update rtp for each plugin installed. Am I totally wrong?

Comment: @AdrienGiboire, Ingo, moi et quelques autres pensons que ce genre de distribution est mauvaise pour les débutants et que, notamment, configurer Vim fait partie intégrante de l'apprentissage. Ce qu'Ingo dit, c'est qu'il existe des mécanismes pour limiter l'impact des plugins sur le temps de lancement et que c'est la responsabilité de leurs auteurs de les utiliser. Si un plugin spécifique à un langage, disons HTML, n'utilise pas `ftplugin/html.vim` c'est une bonne raison de ne pas l'utiliser.

Comment: @romainl: Merci :) That's what I understood then. Despite the fact the author should do it in a certain way, there is no alternative, then?